# MySQL column comments and performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I have to add new column to database table but its name is relatively ambiguous and I thought a comment on the column would be perfectly utilised and would give good insight for the developers down the line.

But the questions is, does the column comment have any impact on the SQL queries and their performance generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are just extra description on the structure of your table. Don't worry about ambiguity. `ALIAS` is here to help you.